# Differences between "The Science of" versus "The Art of?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, scientific-method

Suppose you go to a book store and you see two books titled:

```
The Science of Cooking
The Art of Cooking
```

Before opening the books, how would you expect them to differ? What kinds of things would you expect to be in The Science of Cooking that you would not expect to be in The Art of Cooking, and vice versa?

My question applies not only to cooking but to many other things:

```
The Science of Artificial Intelligence
The Art of Artificial Intelligence

The Science of Home Decorating
The Art of Home Decorating

The Science of Astronomy
The Art of Astronomy
```

In order for a book to legitimately claim that it is "The Science of," what must it contain? How must it differ from books titled "The Art of" or "The Engineering of" or "The Philosophy of" or "The Discipline of"?

Comment: In the late 19th century "the manly science" didn't mean anthropology but boxing, and if someone said "I am a man of science" that meant he was a medical doctor.  And there is a character in a 19th century novel who thinks that "the science of optics" is a high official.

Comment: Hi, welcome to hsm. Your question seems to be more about meaning of words or philosophy than history, so [English SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/) or [Philosophy SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) would be more suitable places to ask.

Comment: Hi @Conifold. Okay, I will ask my question on Philosophy SE. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: When should your degree be Bachelor or Arts, and when should it be Bachelor of Science?

Comment: Interesting question @Gerald Edgar!

Comment: See [*Episteme* and *Techne*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/episteme-techne/).

Comment: Very Interesting question.  I wonder that myself at times.@RogerCostello

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an open ended question. In my understanding, when we use the word "science", it is often implied that one can explain all the observations from known scientific principles. On the other hand, a book or a paper with a title of "Art of Something" is more like a personal account of tips and tricks used by the author and the author may not explain all his/her actions on a scientific basis.

Consider food chemists, who may know all the chemical changes that take place during cooking, but certainly they may not have excellent cooking skills, because they may not have personal experience or know good tips/tricks  (=art) of cooking.

The dictionary definition of art is *"A practical application of knowledge; (hence) something which can be achieved or understood by the employment of skill and knowledge; (in early use also) a body or system of rules serving to facilitate the carrying out of certain principles."* (Unabridged Oxford English Dictionary)

Comment: Thank you @M. Farooq